# Sum of non-primitive array elements with reduce() vs forEach()

Tags: javascript, arrays, cumulative-sum

I've played with the following piece of code and I can't explain why the results differ:

```js
let foo = [];
let bar = [...foo, {
  a: 1
}, {
  a: 2
}];

let sum = bar.reduce((a, b) => a.a + b.a, 0);
console.log(sum); // prints NaN

sum = 0;
bar.forEach((element) => {
  sum += element.a;
});
console.log(sum); // prints 3
```

Comment: `a.a` is undefined because a is 0 in first iteration

Comment: `(a, b) => a + b.a` gives the expected result; the accumulator in `reduce` is an integer, not an object

Comment: Replace this with `bar.reduce((a, b) => ((a && a.a) ? a.a : 0) + b.a, 0)`

Comment: Or perhaps `bar.reduce((a, b) => ({ a : a.a + b.a }), { a: 0 })` which will return `{ a: 3 }`

Comment: @Nick I guess I have to study up on the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce). I usually see the reduction written the way I wrote it in my question and I assumed `a` and `b` were both array elements. Definitely not a typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that `a` in `(a, b) =>` is the accumulator for `reduce`, and it starts at `0` (the second parameter). This means it has no `a` property, and hence all the subsequent sums end up as `NaN` because you are adding numbers to `undefined` (and subsequently `NaN`). To fix this, just remove the reference to `.a`:

```js
let foo = [];
let bar = [...foo, {
  a: 1
}, {
  a: 2
}];

let sum = bar.reduce((a, b) => a + b.a, 0);
console.log(sum); // prints 3
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is `reduce()` chains and you need to return a value that can be the "next `a`". Since you reference `a.a` on an integer, it goes into `NaN` territory.

```js
let sum = bar.reduce((a, b) => ({ a: a.a + b.a }), { a: 0 });
```

A possibly more efficient way is to normalize the values first:

```js
let sum = bar.map(a => a.a).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
```

Where now it's just a simple array of numbers.

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter of [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) function is an accumulator. By definition

> The accumulator accumulates callback's return values. It is the accumulated value previously returned in the last invocation of the callback—or initialValue, if it was supplied (see below).

If you change from  `a.a` to `a` then it should work.

```
let sum = bar.reduce((a, b) => a + b.a, 0);
```

Comment: Not quite there, though that does go one step closer.

Answer (score 0):

The initial value you are passing to the reduce function is 0 ie. a = 0 and trying to do computation on **undefined + 1** which returns **NaN**. You an do any of the below:

1. Without passing the initial value :

   bar.reduce((a, b) => a.a + b.a);
2. By passing initial value, bur here you need to use map :

   bar.map(a => a.a).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);

There can be more ways though. You can get more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)